# Should the Shliach Tzibur say end-verses quietly to himself before saying them out loud?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, tzibur-community, loud-quiet

The [Shliach Tzibur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazzan) reads most prayers quietly until (about) the last verse, and then reads the last verse out loud (either for the congregation to follow along, or for them to answer Amen). Should the Chazzan finish the paragraph quietly to himself before repeating the last verse out loud, or should he say the last verse out loud as he arrives at that verse, without repeating it.

I would think repeating verses wouldn't be ok, since according to Bruchos 14a-b, when davening, one should not repeat words (aside from times you make a mistake and need to repeat the prayer again), however this may not apply to a Shliach Tzibur who is expected to say those verses out loud.

Comment: I heard in the name of the Gra that the chazan is supposed to repeat "H' Elokeichem Emes" anyway

Comment: @ba I recall the opposite: the Gra held Emet should only be said once, while the standard psak is to always say it twice.

Comment: zaq, I think you are assuming that these things should not be said quietly, when in fact many think that they should. Perhaps you can source your assumptions.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that could answer my question if they're supposed to be repeated after saying them quietly, but I think I was taught to pause before the end and then say the last passuk out loud. Also, according to Bruchos 14a-b one should not repeat words. If one is interrupted after saying "Hashem Elokechem Emet", he should not repeat "Emet" to start the next paragraph, but just continue with "V'yatziv". It could be different for the Chazzan though.

Comment: My vague memory is as good as anyone's but it says that the _Chaye Adam_ holds that only in the case of the end of _Sh'ma_ (i.e. "_Hashem Elokechem, emes_") should the leader repeat the words he said quietly.

Comment: Should I edit this question to "Should a Chazan say end-verses quietly to himself before saying them out loud?"

Comment: You certainly *can*. Sounds like a good idea to me. (Fleshed out more than how you just wrote it in that comment, of course.)

Comment: @zaq Before you do see these relevant questions http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9593/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1988/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9797/759

Comment: These are two separate issues/questions. Shema' is a unique case. You are supposed to say it quietly and then repeat it aloud. Other places, you are just signifying or letting the Kehillah know where you are, so they can begin the next paragraph together.

Comment: @SethJ, Because repeating "Hashem Elokechem Emet" adds three words in place of "El Melech Neeman"?

Comment: @zaq, well, as I understand it, the emphasis is the reverse, but yes. (No source readily at hand, though I suspect M"B says something about it.)

Comment: The custom among Ashkenazim of the Shliah Tzibbur saying the last couple of lines of each psalm in Psukei DeZimra aloud is just a way to let people keep in sync with each other. But it is not fulfilling any halakhic obligation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a source for this, but I don't think there is one (3 months is enough time for bigger Talmidei-Chachmim than me to find one), so I'll use logic (aka Svara).

Ashkenaz minhag is that the shat"z (shliach-tzibur) says the prayer quitely except for last (and maybe also first) verse of each part (and defining "part" is quite... per part). The Sepharad minhag is that shat"z says (almost) the whole prayer out loud. Sepharadim don't repeat the last sentence. So there's certainly no problem "using" the single sentence for two puposes: praying and informing the tzibur that the part is over. I'd say that there's no Isur and Ashkenazim can do the same.

Since there's no problem with saying the last verse once and thus "using" it also for sync with the tzibur, I just don't see any justification for repeating it. Not that it causes great harm, but what for?

---

EDIT: repeating ends of blessings might well be Bracha-Levatalla as DoubleAA mentioned. Also, when the last verse contains Shem Hashem it might also be considered as saying Shem Hashem Lashav (for no justified need).

All-in-all, this leads to a more unequivocal conclusion, that the last verse should not be repeated.

Comment: Is this the minhag in all Ashkenazi style congregations? Those in USA? Israel? Europe? What about those who daven Nussach Sefard or Nussach Ari? Do Chassidim follow this custom as well? When you say Sephardim do you mean those from Spain-Portugal? North Africa? Iraq/Iran? Are these based on your personal observations or what you have heard from others? Do you know if this was their original minhag in their respective countries of origin?

Comment: In any event, your logic that it doesn't cause great harm seems to me to be far-fetched. Would you allow the Chazzan to recite a closing blessing twice? Sounds like a bracha levatalla.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I imagine yair was interpreting "verse" in the question as _pasuk_, a fair interpretation. (I suspect the asker meant it more generally, though.)

Comment: @DoubleAA first, as this is a minhag - and as neither I, nor anyone else in this site up to now, has found a source for the minhag - I based my description on my observations (mostly) in Israel. It includes too various Ashkenzaim and Sepharadim to bother to mention. However, I accept that it'd be good to indicate it in the answer. Second, in my answer I asume that (1) the logic can be based on even one widely acceptable minhag and (2) that the Sepharadim in Israel (and a few places abroad) answers that requirement.

Comment: @DoubleAA (answering second comment second :-)) Although "Not that it causes great harm" is not my main argumnet, you're absolutely right. I didn't refer in my answer to the end of blessings. Although msh210 helps me (dan lechaf zechut), I can say that I _did_ have in mind to indicate that I exclude blessings and to explicitly apply the answer to Korbanot, Psukei Dezimra and the such.

Comment: @DoubleAA in second thought, even when not in end of blessings, if the last verse includes Shem Hashem, it might also be problematic.